# Laravel Backpack filter range amount input width too small

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-backpack

I add a filter range from backpack.

[image]

But the input for the min and max is too small, I want to set the width. How do I set it ?
This is my Code.

```
$this->crud->addFilter([ // daterange filter
    'type' => 'date_range',
    'name' => 'from_to',
    'label' => 'Date',
], false, function ($value) { // if the filter is active, apply these constraints
    $dates = json_decode($value);
    $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '>=', $dates->from);
    $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '<=', $dates->to.' 23:59:59');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the width of the inputs there. But you can easily create a new filter, starting from this one, which is wider, and use that one. You just need to:

1. run `php artisan backpack:publish crud/filters/range`. This will copy-paste the file in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/filters/range.blade.php`.
2. Go to that published file and rename it to `wide_range.blade.php`. Then change the css/html inside it to fit your needs.
3. Change your controller to use the `wide_range` filter instead of `range`.

Then you’ll have a range filter as wide as you want.